# Using Curl to build a string

Tags: php, curl

I need to post this string to a url :

```
https://sample.nodeurl.tld/api/getObjects.sjs?object=supporter&      condition=Email=chris@dia.org&condition=Last_Modified>2010-05-05&limit=5&orderBy=Last_Modified
```

The issue is with multiple conditions. The following code works with a single condition, but cant figure out how to build a string with multiple conditions.

```
$query = array();
$query ["object"]="supporter";
$query ["condition"]="First_Name= $_POST[fname]";


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($query));
//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Why does it have two `condition=`?  Shouldn't that be `condition[]=`?

Comment: You can't have your own set of = in the URL because it's a special character.

Answer (score 1):

Just make `$query["condition"]` into an array.

```
$query = array(
    'object' => 'supporter',
    'condition' => array(
        'Email=chris@dia.org',
        'Last_Modified>2010-05-05'
    )
);
```

Then `http_build_query` will build you a query string that looks like:

```
object=supporter&condition[]=Email=chris@dia.org&condition[]=Last_Modified>2010-05-05
```

I don't know about other server-side languages, but in PHP the `[]` after condtion makes it into an array when it's posted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to pass this query in POST ?If so You can just use query directly

```
$string = "https://sample.nodeurl.tld/api/getObjects.sjs?object=supporter& condition=Email=chris@dia.org&condition=Last_Modified>2010-05-05&limit=5&orderBy=Last_Modified";
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
```